# Group two columns into one and return

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a controller action which returns StudentID.

```
[HttpPost()]
    public ActionResult DisplayStudents()
    {
        StudentDataContext db = new StudentDataContext ();

        var StudentID = (from s in db.vwStudents.Where(s => s.StudentID != null)
                          group s by s.StudentID into g
                          select g.Key).ToList();

         return Json(new {StudentID});

    }
```

I want to return "StudentName" from the same view as well, but parse the final result and return "StudentID - StudentName" for e.g. "JD11212 - John Deat"

Is there a way where I can group two columns "StudentID" and "StudentName" in one and return that?

Comment: Why are you grouping students into groups of one or is your StudentID not unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
group s by new {s.StudentID, s.StudentName} into g
...
```

This will create a new anonymous type {StudentID, StudentName} which should be what you are looking for.

Comment: How do I return a sting to Json though? Is there a way to parsing the object {s.StudentID, s.StudentName} and returning "StudentID - StudentName" as a string?

Comment: Do you really want "StudentID - StudentName" at the other end? (Having two fields might be more meaningful, easier to work with, and separates the presentation layer from the business/data storage layer). If so, you could just select `g.Key.StudentID + " - " + g.Key.StudentName`.